# Using wkHtmlToPdf, images replaced with small boxes after 100+ pages

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

Using wkHtmlToPdf to turn a long HTML document (a manual) into a PDF. Often, after a number of pages - about 100 or so, the images are replaced with a little square grey box of a couple of pixels in dimension.

Sometimes this does not happen at all and the document is generated, and the page where it does happen is not the same each time.

Presumably this is a resource issue of some sort - but given it does sometimes work that seems strange, we've tried doubling RAM to no effect.

Any ideas on how we debug this?